# How can I seal a mouse hole with a refrigerator water line running through it?

Tags: drywall, mice

I've traced my mouse problems back to a large hole in the wall behind my fridge.  The problem is, there's a line running through it--I assume it's the water line, as there is a black power cord plugging the fridge into the wall elsewhere.  How can I seal this hole without messing with the water line?  I have "Great Stuff" gaps and cracks sealant spray--will that work?  Pictures attached of hole.  Thanks in advance for any and all advice!

[image: Top view]

Comment: You're playing whack-a-mole. The mice aren't entering the building envelope there. If you seal a hole in drywall they'll make another one. Seal the actual entrance.

Comment: Best to remove mice problem first, before patching, next place might not be so nice.  They can also chew power cables and plastic water pipes, both bad news.

Comment: @isherwood you're right, but unfortunately I live in an apartment but there's only so much I can do on that front unless the landlord gets off his lazy ass and handles it himself.  Even if it's a band-aid, would sealing this hole help?

Comment: Get some steel wool and put it in there with some ally cat food bars. (Ally cat is a brand and mice eat it and go away.

Comment: Wouldn't feeding the mice make the problem worse?

Comment: @EdBeal  “tomcat”is a brand of poison I have not seen “ally cat”brand in my area

Comment: @kris oh my gosh no wonder it makes them go away. We used to use that in the barn before we purchased the mouse swimming pool with a diving board, turns out that mice can’t swim well. Check out walk the plank devices I think our first one wore out after several hundred barn mice. I could have fixed it but who wants to mess with a 7$ item that mice have been all over. A few years back a man in southern oregon almost died after trying to save a mouse from his cat the cat and mouse did die. It sounded like the Black Plague nasty critters.

Answer (score 5):

**Whooooaaaa!**

***Leaking refrigerator lines are the #1 cause for house damage.***   They are usually on the main floor, in an expensive area of the house, and once they start leaking water just pours out.

So mouse issue is one thing.   A mouse issue (they bite EVERYTHING) next to a fridge water line - disaster waiting to happen.   Ticking time bomb.

You are going to do a 2 for 1.   Have less of a chance for water issues and get rid of that hole.

**Step 1 - Buy a fridge shutoff valve**

[image]

**Step 2 - Take out drywall and install  valve**

You need to cut out a small rectangle - 12x18"ish.   Put Shutoff valve on a stud, attach it.   Put water line into the valve - test it.   Replace drywall over it.

**Step 3 - Basic mud and tape and plug back line to fridge.**
It's behind a fridge so you don't have to be perfect.

So hole is gone and your fridge line meets modern plumbing code.

Comment: Excellent points and a great answer. Unfortunately, OP is a tenant and the landlord sounds like he won't allow this level of work by his renter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and duct tape worked for me but another post above is right that they’ll find another way in if you don’t block off all possible access.

Comment: Don't duct tape walls. That's not what duct tape is for, and when the summer comes, the glue will melt and you have a bigger mess.